# Emacs eshell. How to read content of command-line on pressing RET

Tags: emacs, command-line, elisp, eshell

My intention is to use `bm.el` *[Visible Bookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/VisibleBookmarks)* for each prompt as I press *RET*.  I have managed to achieve this to a some degree.. Please comment on my code, below, if it is missing some important issue: eg. I have no idea if I need to handle the args beyond just passing them on to the default function.

When I press *RET* on an empty command line, I do not want to bookmark that line. How can I intercept the command line content before passing contol on to the default function `eshell-send-input`?

```
(defun eshell-send-input-zAp (&optional use-region queue-p no-newline)
  "eshell-send-input, customized to add bm-bookmark to prompt line"
 (interactive)
  (bm-bookmark-add)
  (eshell-send-input use-region queue-p no-newline))

(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (define-key eshell-mode-map
                [return]
                'eshell-send-input-zAp)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks decent.  If you read the code of `eshell-send-input`, you'll see how to get the current input.

Also read up on [interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html) arguments.  `"P"` is required to pass the user-region on to `eshell-send-input`.

```
(defun eshell-send-input-zAp (&optional use-region queue-p no-newline)
  "eshell-send-input, customized to add bm-bookmark to prompt line"
  (interactive "*P")
  (unless (string-equal (eshell-get-old-input use-region) "")
    (bm-bookmark-add))
  (eshell-send-input use-region queue-p no-newline))
```

Comment: It works nicely. Thanks for clearing the fog... With all the good help, I am gradually cracking this *elisp* nut :)

Answer (score 1):

`esh-mode` defines a variable `eshell-last-output-end` which it updates each time the output is printed. So, you can grab the string which is to be sent to the shell by doing something like `(buffer-substring eshell-last-output-end (point-max))` I believe.

EDIT: quote from the documentation on `eshel-send-input`:

> "Send the input received to Eshell for parsing and processing. **After
>   eshell-last-output-end, sends all text from that marker to point as
>   input.**  Before that marker, calls `eshell-get-old-input' to retrieve
>   old input, copies it to the end of the buffer, and sends it.
>
> If USE-REGION is non-nil, the current region (between point and mark)
>   will be used as input.
>
> If QUEUE-P is non-nil, input will be queued until the next prompt,
>   rather than sent to the currently active process.  If no process, the
>   input is processed immediately.
>
> If NO-NEWLINE is non-nil, the input is sent without an implied final
>   newline."

Accent is mine. And if you look into the source of `eshel-send-input`, you may get the idea of how it is used.

To reflect on event_jr's answer - you don't necessarily need to pass universal argument to this function if your own function has no such option... Obviously, so far you have no use for that, that's sort of unnecessary.

Comment: I haven't been able to get anything running from `eshell-last-output-end`. Its documentation says: *Not documented as a variable.*

Comment: Mhh.. the `esh-mode` and `eshel-` part was a bit puzzling, but is seems that *each* hyphenated segment of a name has its own completion.. I seem to have a few too many *bash* preconceptions.... (reading up on it all now...

Comment: Thanks for the good references.. I've learn't an few new points.. (ond there are quite a few to go, in elisp, in general :)

Answer (score 0):

(Answering my own question)... I realized that `eshell` is at its core just an emacs buffer, So, with that in mind, I've come up with this method, which does work, but perhaps could be done better. Maybe there is something about it which I'm yet unaware of, so I'm still open to suggestions.

```
(defun eshell-send-input-zAp (&optional use-region queue-p no-newline)
  "A customized `eshell-send-input`, to add bm-bookmark to prompt line" 
  (interactive)
  (let ((line (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol))))
    (if (string-match eshell-prompt-regexp line)
        (if (> (length (substring line (match-end 0))) 0)
            (bm-bookmark-add))))
  (eshell-send-input use-region queue-p no-newline))
```